# Google suggest API does not work with Chinese locale

Tags: api, localization, locale, cjk

I have a problem with Google suggest API when using Chinese locale. I am picking Chinese hieroglyphs at random and use the REST API to retrieve suggestions. Unfortunately, Google always return an empty list of suggestions (I am completely sure, that I convert my request in utf-8, and it is working fine with other languages, ex. Russian):

Sample request:

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?qu=%E9%80%9F

Google answer:

window.google.ac.h(["速",[]])

Does anyone know how to retrieve suggestions for Chinese locale? Maybe I am missing some flags or something? Maybe there is an official document from Google, saying that Chinese is not supported? And are there any people from China, using Google toolbar? Does it really work? I'd appreciate any help!

If it matters, I am writing a simple WinAPI application, using C++...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/03/local-flavor-for-google-suggest.html says, at the bottom, that google suggest now supports "155 domains in 51 languages."  This implies a possible solution, which is that you need to use the relevant domain.

http://suggestqueries.google.cn/complete/search?qu=%E9%80%9F

gives me

```
window.google.ac.h(["速",[["速腾","2,020,000 结果","0"] ...
```

A bit of experimentation shows that I'm able to get results for japanese only from google.co.jp, but not from google.com.  I'm in Japan, YMMV.

Comment: +1 I've got the same results. By the way, I receive 速 suggestions for both Chinese and Japanese (and I wonder whether they mean the same) =) Thanks!

Comment: The character means "fast" in Japanese, pretty sure It's similar in Chinese.  If you go to http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=901f and scroll down, you can see english translations of many words incorporating it.  

FWIW, the first few suggestions from google.co.jp are "speed measurement" (i.e. bandwidth test), "speed checker" (same thing), "express delivery", and "express delivery rate table".  In case you were wondering. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I don't know it seems to work for me. e.g

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?qu=%e6%9c%a8

yields

```
window.google.ac.h(["木",[["木村了","297,026 results","0z"]]])
```

Comment: Hmm. I click on your link from my browser and receive window.google.ac.h(["木",[]])... What country are you from?

Comment: I'm from Austria and the link worked when I posted, but now yields now result for me too. But when I use .cn instead of .com (suggested by Russel Mull) it gives normal results for me